# Win 8.1 Hot Corners Not Working. And I Want It To Stay That Way

Tags: windows-8.1

So, yeah. Like the title says, my Win8.1 Vaio's Hot Corners have suddenly stopped working --
the top left app-switcher, the top/bottom right Charms-bar activator, and even the bottom left Start button.

I checked the Settings and it shows -

[image]

And yet no active corners.
I don't know why, I don't know how.

But I want it to stay that way, because mine's a touchscreen and I don't need the Corners.
I mean, I do use a mouse with it, but, still; the accidental corner clicks are too irritating.

I haven't shutdown or restarted my notebook in three days just so I don't accidentally reset whatever it is that's causing this "malfunction".

Can anyone help me figure out how to make this permanent?

Comment: If you want it to stay that way what's the question?

Comment: I want to be able to restart the system without resetting whatever it is that's causing the problem.

Comment: For what it's worth, Charms are supposed to be removed in Windows 9 (here's hoping), as well as an option to go back to a windowed start menu. The fixes you want might be just around the corner.

Comment: Ehh, I like the Charms bar. I just prefer to access it by touch.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the behavior started, but you can make it permanent with a few registry edits. The How To Geek has a great tutorial on how to do that:

[How To Disable the Charms Bar and Switcher Hot Corners in Windows 8](http://www.howtogeek.com/127645/how-to-disable-the-charms-bar-and-switcher-hot-corners-in-windows-8/)

I personally recommend a few of his other fixes to Windows 8 annoyances. It's the first place I go when I do an new OS install:

[How to Get Rid of the Modern Environment on a Windows 8 PC](http://www.howtogeek.com/163424/how-to-get-rid-of-the-modern-environment-on-a-windows-8-pc/)

Comment: I'm more concerned about the Start button. 

I have my taskbar on the left side of the screen, so the Show Desktop button's in the bottom left corner. 
But every time I move my mouse to the corner, I end up moving to the EXTREME bottom left pixel, which ends up showing me that Start icon, which ends up covering the Show Desktop button >_<

Comment: In my research it seems like it's only possible in Win 8.1 to disable the top left (Switcher) hot corner and the top right (Charms) corner. The bottom left (Start menu) corner can only be disabled with 3rd party tools like [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/). That's the solution I opted for. If you reboot and lose your awesome glitch, you can try using the keyboard shortcut Win + D to show your desktop. That should avoid the troublesome corner.